# How can I apply and use Vodafone Australia firmware/USIM on my Samsung Galaxy SIII SHV-210S?

Tags: samsung-galaxy-s-3, device-firmware

Over last 1.5 years, I've been using a Samsung Galaxy S2 on Australia's Vodafone network. I got a Samsung Galaxy S3 (SHV-210S - South Korea SKTelecom version) and want to format it with Vodafone Australia firmware and USIM. With Vodafone Australia USIM to SHV-210S, I can make a call, send/receive SMS/MMS, but some settings/configurations are not fully catered for Vodafone Australia.

Would Australia Vodafone S3 (GT-I9300) firmware be compatible to apply to a SHV-210S device?